# researching the css property to fix the square outline issue that cuts off the image like there is a smaller square outline in the background

Tags: css

I'm trying to locate the CSS property that cuts off the design of the button once it is pressed.

I've tried to locate the CSS property in the Inspect window looking at the box model.

Below, I put the picture and the button's css:

STYLES.CSS

```
.flag-pictures {
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
text-align: center;
border: 0;
outline: none;
margin: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
background-size: 100%;
}

.flag-button {
position: relative;

background: -webkit-radial-gradient( hsl(54, 100%, 50%), hsl(54, 100%, 40%) );
background: -o-radial-gradient( hsl(54, 100%, 50%), hsl(54, 100%, 40%) );
background: -moz-radial-gradient( hsl(54, 100%, 50%), hsl(54, 100%, 40%) );
background: radial-gradient( hsl(54, 100%, 50%), hsl(54, 100%, 40%) );
font-size: 1.4rem;
color: white;
margin: 20px 20px 20px 0;
padding-left: 0px;

border-left-width: 0px;
border-radius: 100%;
height: 80px;
width: 80px;
z-index: 4;

outline: none;

box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 50%),
          0 2px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 20%),
          0 3px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 18%),
          0 4px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 16%),
          0 5px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 14%),
          0 6px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 12%),
          0 7px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 10%),
          0 8px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 8%),
          0 9px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 6%);
}
.flag-button:hover {
background: -webkit-radial-gradient( hsl(54, 100%, 45%), hsl(54, 100%, 35%) );
background: -o-radial-gradient( hsl(54, 100%, 45%), hsl(54, 100%, 35%) );
background: -moz-radial-gradient( hsl(54, 100%, 45%), hsl(54, 100%, 35%) );
background: radial-gradient( hsl(54, 100%, 45%), hsl(54, 100%, 35%)); 

border-bottom-width: 0px;
height: 80px;
width: 80px;
outline: none;
}

.flag-button:active {
background: -webkit-radial-gradient( hsl(54, 100%, 43%), hsl(54, 100%, 33%) );
background: -o-radial-gradient( hsl(54, 100%, 43%), hsl(54, 100%, 33%) );
background: -moz-radial-gradient( hsl(54, 100%, 43%), hsl(54, 100%, 33%) );
background: radial-gradient( hsl(54, 100%, 43%), hsl(54, 100%, 33%) );

top: 2px;
height: 80px;
width: 80px;
outline: none;

box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 50%),
          0 2px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 20%),
          0 3px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 18%),
          0 4px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 16%),
          0 5px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 14%),
          0 6px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 12%),
          0 7px 0 hsl(54, 100%, 10%);
}

.flag-presentation {
list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 0px;
}

#hiddenMessage {
/* margin-top: 10px; */
font-size: 1.5rem;
font-family: Arial;
}

.profile {
margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.skill-row {
width: 50%;
margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
text-align: left;
}

.skill-pics {
height: 15%;
width: 15%;
border-radius: 100%;
float: left;
margin-right: 30px;
}

.body-h2 {
font-size: 2rem;
color: #66BFBF;
padding: 50px auto 50px auto;
}

h3 {
font-size: 1.5rem;
color: #66BFBF;
}

.footer-link {
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

INDEX.HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="top-container">
    <div class="top-nav">
      <header>
        <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
</div>


<img class="invert" src="images/cloud.png" id="cloud1" alt="cloud-img">
<h1 class="h1-title">I'm Tim Otom</h1>
<h2 class="h2-title">Football dreamer</h2>
<img class="invert" src="images/cloud.png" id="cloud2" alt="cloud-img">
<img src="images/eiffel.png" id="eiffel" alt="eiffel-img">

  </div>
  </header>
  <div class="middle-container">

  <ul class="flag-presentation">


  <button class="flag-button" onclick="revealMessage('Hello!')">
    <li><img class="flag-pictures" src="images/uk.svg" id="1" alt='UK' /></li>
  </button>
  <button class="flag-button" onclick="revealMessage('¡Hola!')">
    <li><img class="flag-pictures" src="images/spain.svg" id="3" alt='Spain' /></li>
  </button>

  <p id="hiddenMessage" style="display:none"></p>


</ul>
</div>
...
</body>
```

FOR THE SVG IMAGE I USE, here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bz1yoonvj99g3gq/uk.svg?dl=1

I'm unable to locate that glitch. Anything you spotted being incorrect? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks correct to me: https://jsfiddle.net/92rupcLt/

Can you post your HTML and maybe add an image of what exactly is wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem i see no outline, try to strip the code you provided to highlight only the issue. side note `li` must be direct child of `ul`

Comment: @timotom thanks. Since you are using `<button>` elements, do you maybe mean the default button stylings (grey border)? If so, add `border: 0;` to your `.flag-button` see https://jsfiddle.net/vcj9kr3L/

Comment: @elveti Thanks very much. Adding 'border: 0' is the solution.